# .val() as part of the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 5 different tables with the ids *table_1,...,table_5* with the class *table_class* and a selection which with the value 1,...,5.

**Example:**
I wanted that when in the selection the option 4 is selected that all the tables are hidden, except the table with the id table_4. I'm able to hide them aso. But I'm unable to combine the .val() with the name, so that i can get the name table_4 as selector...

```
$("#tables_"+$(this).val()).show();
```

Could please someone help me...

Thanks

Comment: It seems okay. Did you try this? Did you print `$(this).val()` to the console to check its value?

Comment: What you've written should be fine, provided you know what `this` is, and it's the element you think it is. You should be able to debug that much yourself.

Comment: can you alert/log the value of `$(this).val()`

Comment: `$(".table_class").hide(); $("#tables_"+$(this).val()).show();`

Comment: `$(this).val()` is just silly anyway. Just use `this.value` - it's quite a lot more to the point.

Comment: @m59 -- you assume knowledge that jQuery isn't providing compatability services/improved API over the top of the DOM. Generally, this is the reason we all use jQuery in the first place! Simplicity & consistency are best served by _just using the library we've agreed to use_, rather than trying to pointlessly optimize corner-cases. How many total man-hours are developers going to spend, every time they look at the code, to determine that `this.value` is (mostly) the same as `$(this).val()`? Asking other developers why different & is this correct? What a huge waste of productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your selecter id instead of this.

```
$("#tables_"+$('#myselecter').val()).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the safest way to do it, but yes, your code works fine. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4CDe/2/)

```
$('select').change(function() {
   $('table').hide();
   $('#table_' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```